# Generate two different CSV file on one single button

Tags: apex, visualforce, community

I want to download 2 different CSV files.

Created a page Wizard1.

```
<apex:page controller="AssignController">
```

function redirectBack(){
            window.location.href = '/apex/DownloadCSVFileOfAccount';
}

```
 <apex:form >
     <apex:commandButton value="Preview" action="{!PreviewAccount}"         oncomplete="redirectBack();"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         </apex:form >
```

apex page DownloadCSVFileOfAccount1

```
<apex:page controller="exportCSVController" cache="true" contentType="text/csv#Export.csv" language="en-US">
"Col A","Col B"
<apex:repeat value="{!myList}" var="a">
    <apex:repeat value="{!a}" var="asub">
    {!asub.val1},"{!asub.val2}"
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:repeat>
```

```
    public class exportCSVController {
    public List<List<myClass>> myList {get;set;}
    
    public exportCSVController() {
        myList = new List<List<myClass>>();
        List<myClass> temp = new List<myClass>();
        
        for(Integer i = 0; i < 5000; i++){
            if(temp.size() < 1000){
                myClass m = new myClass();
                m.val1 = 'val1 ' + i;
                m.val2 = 'val2 ' + i;
                temp.add(m);
            }
            else{
                myList.add(temp);
                temp = new List<myClass>();
                myClass m = new myClass();
                m.val1 = 'val1 ' + i;
                m.val2 = 'val2 ' + i;
                temp.add(m);
            }
        }
        myList.add(temp);
    }
    
    public class myClass{
        public string val1 {get;set;}
        public string val2 {get;set;}
    }
}
```

apex page DownloadCSVFileOfAccount2 will same as above.

On click of Preview command button I have to call both visualforce page to get my csv file downloaded.

Comment: where is another visualforce page for csv file. I can see only one page with content-type `csv`

Comment: you can give any name to that VF page it will be same as DownloadCSVFileOfAccount1. I have written in the comment